# Create a New Table with DAX in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Let's say I have a table in power bi called TABLE_1 that looks like this:

```
Category        Color
electronic      yellow
automobile      Red
food product    green
educational     black
```

Using a DAX statement, how can I create an EXACT copy of this table?

I am new to DAX

Comment: Table_2 = ALL(Table_1)

Comment: Post this as the answer so I can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use ALL function:

```
Table_2 = ALL(Table_1)
```

If you need to copy a table and filter out some records:

```
Table_2 = CALCULATETABLE( Table_1, Table_1[Color] in {"green", "black"})
```